# c# - programa que imprima números del 1 al 20 y pregunte si desea continuar

Tags: c#

Deseo por favor que me ayuden a terminar este trabajo en c#. Se trata de un programa que imprima los números en grupos de 20 hasta el 1000 y que haga la pregunta de si desea continuar imprimiendo los números en cada grupo.

Si la respuesta es si los números tienen que continuar imprimiendo hasta el 40 y hacer la misma pregunta de nuevo. Y si la respuesta es no, se debe poner un Break. La sintaxis que tengo hasta el momento hace los necesario pero solo hace la  primera pregunta, pongo SI, los números no se imprimen hasta el 40 sino hasta el 1000(que es hasta donde deben imprimirse los números, repito, en grupos de 20). ademas de que otro requisito es que la sintaxis no tiene que ser tan larga y solo puede tener un for.

Solo necesito que la pregunta repita en cada múltiplo de 20.

Aquí esta mi sintaxis:

```
        int i;
        string res;

        for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(4, i);
            Console.Write(i);

            if (i == 20)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(8, 21);
                Console.Write("¿Desea continuar?");
                res= Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                if (res == "si")
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (res != "si")
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        Console.read();
        Console.clear();
```

Comment: cuandoun numero es multiplo de 20?

Comment: @gbianchi son los números que al dividirse entre 20 de un numero entero. ejemplo: 20, 40, 60, 80,100, 120,,, que en el caso de mi programas se tiene que generar la pregunta que cada uno de estos números.

Comment: por qué no empiezas el bucle for contando desde 20?

Answer (score 4):

Respecto al problema principal:

`if (i == 20)` detecta si el número es 20.

`if (i % 20 == 0)` detectaría si el número dividido por 20 da como resto 0, que serían todos los múltiplos de 20, que es lo que estás buscando.

Por otra parte, a la hora de acortar el código...

Esta parte del código 'sobra':

```
if (res == "si")
{
    continue;
}
```

ya que el bucle for se encarga de la continuidad.

Te falta una llave de cerrado (que supongo que habrá sido un error al copiar y pegar)

Y por último, para mejorar la experiencia de usuario, deberías cambiar

```
Console.Write("¿Desea continuar?");
```

por algo como

```
Console.Write("¿Desea continuar? (si/no)");
```